# Using BottomNavigationView to change FloatingActionButton Icon

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments

BottomNavigationView.setOnItemSelectedListener overrides base behavior, but I want to extend, not override, how do I do this?

I have a 4 fragment app that I, using the material BottomNavigationView (navView) on MainActivity. I have a FloatingActionButton (fab) on the MainActivity. When I click on a navView item, in addition to navigating to the selected fragment, I want to change the icon on the fab. I want to use the default navigation behavior of the navView, but with navView.setOnItemSelectedListener (using this to change the icon), I lose the expected base behavior, change fragment. Return true or false does not help.

I want to do this, and also change fragments. How can I navigate using the inherited behavior of the navView

```
 binding.navView.setOnItemSelectedListener {item ->
        val str =item.itemId.toString()
        Snackbar.make(binding.root, str, Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT)
            .setAction("Action", null)
            .show()
        return@setOnItemSelectedListener true // false, behavior appears the same
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't use the default behavior, I wrote code to navigate.

1. This calls methods to navigate to the fragment and setup the initial icon for the fab

   private fun setupNavController() {
   val navHostFragment = supportFragmentManager
   .findFragmentById(...) as NavHostFragment
   val navController = navHostFragment.navController
   NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(
   binding.navView,
   navController
   )
   binding.navView.setOnItemSelectedListener {item ->
   when (item.itemId) { // need method call because can't do fab in ->
   R.id.navigation_1 -> F1()
   R.id.navigation_2 -> F2()
   R.id.navigation_3 -> F3()
   R.id.navigation_4 -> F4()
   }
   return@setOnItemSelectedListener true
   }
   }
2. This responds to the fab click

   private fun setFabNavigationAndIcon() {
   val currentBottomMenuId = binding.navView.selectedItemId
   when (currentBottomMenuId) {
   R.id.navigation_dashboard -> {
   val intent = Intent(this, AnActivity::class.java).apply { }
   startActivity(intent)
   }
   R.id.f1 -> {
   ...
   }
   R.id.f2 -> {
   binding.fragmentContainerView.findNavController().navigate(...
   // change the icon
   binding.fab.setImageDrawable(
   resources.getDrawable(
   ...
   baseContext.theme
   )
   )
   }
   R.id.f3 -> {
   binding.fragmentContainerView.findNavController().navigate(...
   // change the icon so user can go back to list

   ```
        }
    }
   ```